What does the Bible define as Magic?
The Bible warns us not to participate, engage with, or practice magic. The Bible would not do that if magic wasn't real, so my question is this:
 What is it? 

Magic was clearly real... what are you defining as magic? Is it just things without an explanation? A 175 page document, 3.5 hr video, and/or multiple books are not the best sources without snippets supporting your claim.

God's miracles could be called "magic" by the modern definition, but have you found any examples of real magic anywhere else? The word doesn't appear in the NT, and the OT occurrences are a Hebrew word that means "diviner, magician, astrologer, engraver, writer (only in derivative sense of one possessed of occult knowledge)", that is someone with a lot of knowledge not known to the ordinary person. ¶ "the spirit of Samuel was summoned" — was it? or was Saul simply tricked into believing that? ¶ The Title says "Magic was clearly real", but without actual examples, it isn't at all clear.

Also, the one significant reference provided (but not quoted from), the Eastern Orthodox perspective, says "According  to the  researchers,  occultism  is  claimed  to  be  "something  secret, hidden,  reserved  only   for  the  initiated,  something  that  is  learned  and transmitted in the shadows".".  It matches the biblical definition of knowledge that is withheld from the common people. Nothing supernatural is involved, except as the practitioners choose to present it as such.

This is not a question about 'Christianity'. It is a question about certain aspects of the creation that are touched upon by the biblical record.

Depperm, I was literally asking for a definition.
Ray, I don't think Saul was tricked... because Samuel harshly rebuked him. I don't think some random charlatan would have done that.
Nigel- Yes, this is. I'm asking for the definition of Magic according to christianity. The Bible warns against it, but what it is it I'm supposed to avoid? D&D? or dancing naked in the woods? Both could be demonic or innocent.

@RayButterworth Witchcraft and it's ilk is mentioned in the new testament and not just in Revelations.

I'd suggest nailing this down to a particular denomination,  asking for Muslim opinions is clearly off topic- maybe you're thinking of cross posting the question, but please adapt it for the audience.  I think Sola Scriptura Christians are going to have a very different opinion on this question than Medieval Catholics (who rear their heads from time to time)

I vote to reopen, improving it maybe 1) by tagging this as a "terminology" question similar to questions asking for a definition of "miracle" or 2) (per @PeterTurner) by scoping it to eastern orthodox / catholicism (or both, if the answer is the same).  I think OP's logic that this is a Christian question is sound, and does have Biblical precedent since how is it the Bible teaches to prohibit something but we Christians don't quite know how to define what is to be avoided?  Similar to our responsibility to define who the "false teacher / prophet" in the NT is in order to avoid them.

I will rewrite the question, in terms that are less likely to be misunderstood. Possibly to the level that anyone could understand what my question is. I am disappointed, but I'll do it.

@Wyrsa, when asking a question, less is often better than more. I've voted to reopen.

The website actively encourages you to show that you have attempted to resolve the question yourself. So I did my best to do so. This edit does the opposite.

The short version is that the supernatural is certainly real; that is, there are Powers in (and "above") Creation that are not limited to "natural law". For that matter, "natural law" is nothing more than God's actions, when God is acting in an orderly way. It seems to be the case that God does not allow significant interference by other spiritual powers, but as noted, there is clear evidence that such interference has occurred on at least some occasions.
The Scriptural definition of "magic" is calling upon spiritual forces to manipulate Creation in ways that are not approved by God. In particular, "magic" usually involves rituals or other formulaic means believed to have the power to "coerce" spiritual forces (usually demonic ones) in order to achieve a result. The belief that demons can be "coerced" is false, but they might play along in order to draw people away from God. (Thus, it is impossible to identify specific "requirements".)
As to what is possible, the broad answer would be "anything demonic forces can do". Scripture indicates that this includes falsifying miracles (e.g. many Protestants believe that the Miracle of the Sun is such a forgery; Scripture records others, such as turning sticks into snakes or calling up a plague of frogs) as well as calling on the "dead" to obtain knowledge. (In the latter case, what answers isn't the actual soul of a deceased person, but a demon pretending to be that person, with a notable exception as recorded in 1 Samuel 28.)

"a demon pretending to be that person, with a notable exception as recorded in 1 Samuel 28" — Why do you say this is an exception? See my answer to exegesis - According to soul sleep adherents, what's wrong with an "Occam's razor" interpretation of 1 Samuel 28 (Saul and the Medium of En-dor)?.

@RayButterworth, my understanding has been that the Medium knew she was actually (normally) communing with demons, and was surprised when the actual spirit of Samuel responded. That is, I understand the story to be noteworthy with respect to both necromancy and soul sleep in being an exception to the usual "rules" of both. Anyway, the point isn't whether 1 Samuel 28 is exceptional, but that most (or maybe all) necromancy isn't really dealing with deceased spirits, but with demons pretending to be such.

@Matthew worth noting of course that many/most magicians and mediums are simply frauds - it's not a hill I'd die on, but I've always thought that the witch of Endor was a fraud, which was why she was so surprised when Samuel appeared. I don't think she'd have been so shocked by a spirit if she was used to talking to actual spirits.

You know I really like that interpretation of why the medium was surprised.

Magic was clearly real, but what was the definition? How was it real?
Do not know exactly what you refer to magic clearly being real. Nevertheless Christian views on magic vary widely among Christian denominations and even amongst individuals.
“The Spirit clearly says that in later times some will abandon the faith and follow deceiving spirits and things taught by demons” (1 Timothy 4:1). Real spiritual power only comes from God, from a right relationship with Him through faith in Jesus Christ, and from the Holy Spirit who lives in the hearts of believers.

Christian views on magic vary widely among Christian denominations and among individuals. Many Christians actively condemn magic as satanic, holding that it opens the way for demonic possession. Some Christians simply view it as entertainment. Conversely, some branches of esoteric Christianity actively engage in magical practices.
Biblical references
There are several references to witchcraft in the Bible that strongly condemn such practices. For example, Deuteronomy 18:11–12 condemns anyone who "casts spells, or who is a medium or spiritist or who consults the dead. Anyone who does these things is detestable to the Lord, and because of these detestable practices the Lord your God will drive out those nations before you", and Exodus 22:18 states "Do not allow a sorceress to live" (or in the King James Bible "thou shalt not suffer a witch to live"). It has also been suggested that the word "witch" (Heb. מְכַשֵּׁפָ֖ה məḵaššêp̄āh) might be a mistranslation of "poisoner."
Others point to a primitive idealist belief in a relation between bewitching and coveting, reflected in the occasional translation of the Tenth Commandment as 'Thou shalt not covet'.[2] This may suggest that the prohibition related specifically to sorcery or the casting of spells to unnaturally possess something.
Some adherents of near-east religions acted as mediums, channeling messages from the dead or from a familiar spirit. The Bible sometimes is translated as referring to "necromancer" and "necromancy" (Deuteronomy 18:11). However, some lexicographers, including James Strong and Spiros Zodhiates, disagree. These scholars say that the Hebrew word kashaph (כשפ), used in Exodus 22:18 and 5 other places in the Tanakh comes from a root meaning "to whisper". Strong, therefore, concludes that the word means "to whisper a spell, i.e. to incant or practice magic". The Contemporary English Version translates Deuteronomy 18:11 as referring to "any kind of magic".
At the very least, older biblical prohibitions included those against 'sorcery' to obtain something unnaturally; 'necromancy' as the practice of magic or divination through demons or the dead, and any forms of malevolent “bewitchery”.
Early Paulian Christianity
The Apostle Paul's Epistle to the Galatians includes sorcery in a list of "works of the flesh". This disapproval is echoed in the Didache, a very early book of church discipline which dates from the mid-late first century.
Christian opposition to witchcraft
Several Christian groups believe in witchcraft and view it as a negative force. Much of the criticism originates among Evangelical Christian groups;[citation needed] many fundamentalist Christians believe that witchcraft is a danger to children. The 2006 documentary Jesus Camp, which depicts the life of young children attending Becky Fischer's summer camp, shows Fischer condemning the Harry Potter novels and telling the students that "Warlocks are enemies of God". While Fischer's summer camp has sometimes been identified as Pentecostal, Fischer is most closely associated with the neo-Pentecostal movement known as the New Apostolic Reformation (NAR).
Among Christian organizations, the NAR is especially aggressive in spiritual warfare efforts to counter alleged acts of witchcraft; the NAR's globally distributed Transformations documentaries by filmmaker George Otis Jr. show charismatic Christians creating mini-utopias by driving off territorial spirits and by banishing or even killing accused witches.[36][citation needed] During the 2008 United States presidential election, footage surfaced from a 2005 church ceremony in which a NAR apostle, Kenyan bishop Thomas Muthee, laid hands on Sarah Palin and called upon God to protect her from "every form of witchcraft". - Christian views on magic (Wikipedia)

A purely Catholic point of view on witchcraft and the occult can be found here: Witchcraft (Catholic Encyclopedia).

I appreciate the detail here. I'm really trying to sift through all the things it can't be and find the proper original definition. Which is likely a Hebrew jewish one that has persisted. Another annoying thing is that it is definitely something that is hidden in the darkness... so hard to define I guess. I found a lot of things like Magic is trying to find shortcuts for things by skipping God.
